# How to maintain two connections to different ElasticSearch hosts using Elastisch?

Tags: clojure, elasticsearch, elastisch

I’m using [Elastisch](http://github.com/clojurewerkz/elastisch), and the `rest/connect` function return an endpoint, but I can’t see how to reuse this endpoint when calling other functions. I need to transfer some documents from one index to another on different hosts, using a scroll on the first one and bulk indexing on the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elastisch also offers the`connect` (without the !) that returns the connection to you instead of storing it in a local var. You can call this twice and then use `binding` to bind the appropriate one for each call.

```
(let [client1 (connect ...)
      client2 (connect ...)
      data (binding [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native/*client* client1] ...)
   (binding [clojurewerkz.elastisch.native/*client* client2] ... put stuff))
```

Comment: Thanks! I’m using the REST api, so I changed from `clojurewerkz.elastisch.native/*client*` to `clojurewerkz.elastisch.rest/*endpoint*`.